# Image only changing once

Tags: javascript, html

So i have two arrow images that I need to switch between on click (dropdown menu sort of thing).

The first click of the button changes the image, however the second click does nothing.

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    function toggle_img(img) {
        var i = document.getElementById(img);
        if(i.src = '/Images/arrow1_unclicked.png') {
            i.src = '/Images/arrow1_clicked.png';
        } else {
            i.src = '/Images/arrow1_unclicked.png';}
     }
    }
    <h1 id="headerSports" onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenSports'), toggle_img('arrow')">
        Sports     <img id="arrow" src="/Images/arrow1_unclicked.png"/>
    </h1>

    <div id="hiddenSports" class="hiddenText">
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenNetball')">Netball</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenNetball" class="hiddenText">Netball</h3>
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenFootball')">Football</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenFootball" class="hiddenText">Football</h3>
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenHockey')">Hockey</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenHockey" class="hiddenText">Hockey</h3> 
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenTennis')">Tennis</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenTennis" class="hiddenText">Tennis</h3>
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenBadminton')">Badminton</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenBadminton" class="hiddenText">Badminton</h3>
        <h2 onclick="toggle_visibility('hiddenRugby')">Rugby</h2>
          <h3 id="hiddenRugby" class="hiddenText">Rugby</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you left something out: "toggle_visibility is not defined" error when I click "Sports". Can you supply the missing code?

Comment: Apologies, I renamed the changeImage function to toggle_visibility. I will edit as according now

Comment: If you console.log or alert i.src before your "if" statement, I think you will find that it's not what you think it's going to be.

Comment: Added console logs to the script, keeps thinking source is 'unclicked' rather than clicked... Not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is using single "=" instead use "==" or "===" for comparison

Comment: Non-coalescing "===" would be appropriate here.

Comment: When I change this, the arrow does not change the first tim

Comment: Added "===" with @Mic suggestion. +1

Comment: toggleVisibilty function may be intrupting, you haven't mentioned its code.

Comment: On h1 what is the use of toggleVisibilty function, toggl_img is sufficient.

Comment: With the single = (assignment operator) it will complete the assignment and then return the value, in this case the String '/Images/arrow1_unclicked.png'. So essentially it's evaluated as if('/Images/arrow1_unclicked.png'). This will always evaluate as true because a string in a trueish (truey?) value.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?
https://jsfiddle.net/oakley808/eje1rof4/

```
var unclicked = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000563115809/b5bfa0c4b2e8670d09222c17856abef4.jpeg'
var clicked = 'http://www.heromachine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/smily-face.jpg'

function toggle_visibility(img) {

  var e = document.getElementById(img)

  if (e.style.display == 'block') {
    e.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    e.style.display = 'block'
  }
}

function toggle_img(img) {
  var i = document.getElementById(img)

  if (i.src == unclicked ) {
    i.src = clicked
  } else {
    i.src = unclicked
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am trying to achieve, however when I change the variables to the local ones on my machine the toggle does not work

Comment: If you post something on jsfiddle or codepen we can help you debug it.